# change datatype of json string to Datetime in spark

Tags: json, datetime, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i am feeding json files to spark. A value in it is of Datetime type but it is being converted to string type. I got a solution here which said to rebuild spark after changing InferSchema.scala file of it but i dont want to do it. Is there any way i can convert it while reading json files. Also can i convert it using spark sql after "jsonFiles.registerTempTable('jsonFiles')". Any help in this regard will be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to follow the instructions you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `jsonFile` function you can also specify the schema at read time so:

`sqlContext.jsonFile(path, schema)` or in the new API (post 1.4) `sqlContext.read.schema(schema).format("json").load(path)`